# cant append list to list python

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

Im simply trying to make a database by making a list of lists where each item in D is a list of numbers split up by using line.split

```
D = [] 

f1 = open("test.txt",'r')
for line in f1:
    trans  = line.split()
    D.append[trans]
```

this is what is in test.txt

```
12 34 34 324 32432 4
23 432 43 557 56 8
124 234 64 457 56
```

when I try this I get back this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "practice.py", line 6, in <module>
    D.append[trans]
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong and how to correctly approach this?

Comment: What are you doing with square brackets at `D.append[trans]`..?

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm not entirely certain this is a simple 'typo'. The OP seems to be new to Python and it is not difficult to get confused as to the difference between '[]' and '()'

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
D.append(trans)
```

This calls the method `append` of the list object `D`. When you do `D.append[...]` you try to index into the `append` attribute. But that attribute is a function/method, so you can't index into it.

Comment: how did i miss that.....wow.......

Comment: @JoseMedina: it's OK, we were all beginners at one time :) The Python error message here could be better, to be fair. It's not very newbie-friendly.

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
D = [] 

f1 = open("test.txt",'r')
for line in f1:
    trans  = line.split()
    D.append(trans)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
D = [] 

f1 = open("test.txt",'r')
for line in f1.getlines():
    trans  = line.split()
    D.append(trans)  # with () instead of [] since this is a function call and not an index
```

You can also say

```
for line in f1:
    print f1
```

to see what f1 really is.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
D.append[trans]
```

That's trying to assign an attribute trans to the attribute append which is a method.  You want

```
D.append(trans)
```

Comment: *That's trying to assign an attribute trans to the attribute append which is a method* -- what...? Nothing is being assigned...